# Emulating RPi using QEMU

Tags: linux, ubuntu, virtual-machine, qemu

I am trying to use QEMU to emulate an RPI running the buster lite raspbian. The command I use is:

```
qemu-system-arm -kernel ~/qemu_vms/kernel-qemu-4.19.50-buster -cpu arm1176 -m 256 -M versatilepb -serial stdio -append "root=/dev/sda2 rootfstype=ext4 rw" -hda ~/qemu_vms/2020-02-13-raspbian-buster-lite.img,format=raw -redir tcp:5022::22 -no-reboot
```

but I get the error:

```
    Automatically detecting the format is dangerous for raw images, write operations on block 0 will be restricted.
         Specify the 'raw' format explicitly to remove the restrictions.
qemu-system-arm: -no-reboot: drive with bus=0, unit=0 (index=0) exists
```

I know the solution is inserting `format=raw` somewhere in the command, but where?

Also [the tutorial I'm using](https://azeria-labs.com/emulate-raspberry-pi-with-qemu/) seems a little dated so If I am using any outdated commands please tell me.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this will work for you (courtesy of `man qemu-system-arm`)

```
qemu-system-arm -kernel ~/qemu_vms/kernel-qemu-4.19.50-buster -cpu arm1176 -m 256 -M versatilepb -serial stdio -append "root=/dev/sda2 rootfstype=ext4 rw" -drive file="$HOME"/qemu_vms/2020-02-13-raspbian-buster-lite.img,format=raw -net user,hostfwd=tcp::5022-:22 -no-reboot
```

Basically, I've updated the disk definition to use `-drive file="$HOME"/qemu_vms/2020-02-13-raspbian-buster-lite.img,format=raw` and the port redirection to `-net user,hostfwd=tcp::5022-:22`